# recursive http request javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, recursion

I'm making a single page app using AngularJS. I want to constantly have a pending http request to the server, so as soon as the server responds, send another http request. I wrote the recursive function stateCheck(), but my code gets stuck inside of the function and never returns the factory and never updates the view.

How do I have these http requests constantly pending in my app without getting stuck inside of an infinite loop?

```
define([
    'angular',
    'app',
    'angularRoute',
    ], function (angular, app) {
        'use strict';

        app.config(function ( $httpProvider) {        
            /* Angular automatically adds this header to the request,
               preventing us from being able to make requests to the server on another port */
            delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        }).factory('equipmentService', ['$http', '$rootScope', function($http, $rootScope) {
            var factory = {
                getEquipmentState: $http.get($rootScope.backendServer+'/equipment/state'),
                setEquipmentState: function(state){
                    this.equipmentState = state.state;
                    console.log('equipment state', this.equipmentState);
                    redirectState(this.equipmentState);
                }
            }
            var redirectState = function (state) {
                switch(state) {
                    case 'Active':
                        $location.path('/active');
                        break;
                    case 'Review':
                        $location.path('/review');
                        break;
                    default:
                        // don't change views
                }
            }

            function stateCheck () {
                factory.getEquipmentState
                .then(function (data) {
                    factory.setEquipmentState(data.data);
                })
                .then(stateCheck);
            }

            stateCheck();

            return factory;
        }]);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the way you initialized `factory.getEquipmentState`. The initialization itself is already invoking a `/GET` request by definition, so accessing the resolved promise within your `stateCheck()` confirms for the first invocation but not for the next.

To solve this problem you can structure your `equipmentService` into something like this:

```
 factory('equipmentService', ['$http', '$rootScope', 
    function($http, $rootScope) {
       var factory = {
          getEquipmentState: function() {
             return this.equipmentState;
          },

          setEquipmentState: function(state){
             this.equipmentState = state.state;
             console.log('equipment state', this.equipmentState);
             redirectState(this.equipmentState);
          }
       };

       var redirectState = function (state) {
          switch(state) {
             case 'Active':
                $location.path('/active');
                break;
             case 'Review':
                $location.path('/review');
             break;
             default:
                // don't change views
          }
       };

       function stateCheck () {
           $http.get($rootScope.backendServer+'/equipment/state')
               .success(function (data) {
                   factory.setEquipmentState(data.data);
               })
               .then(stateCheck);
        }

        stateCheck();

        return factory;
    }])
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that it would reuse the resolved promise. Any recommendations on how to unit test this part? I've been using httpbackend with jasmine, but it will always have an Error: Unexpected request because there will be an infinite number of http requests.

Answer (score 0):

**The problem:**

Your code doesn't work, because you always use the same promise object:

`$http.get($rootScope.backendServer+'/equipment/state')` returns already a promise and will be only resolved once.

**The solution:**

Only save the function with the correct parameters, so change the line

```
getEquipmentState: $http.get($rootScope.backendServer+'/equipment/state'),
```

to

```
getEquipmentState: $http.get.bind($http, $rootScope.backendServer+'/equipment/state'),
```

Call this function in `stateCheck`. This means replace the line

```
factory.getEquipmentState
```

with this line:

```
factory.getEquipmentState()
```

**Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/eQ4dr/2/)**